# Eigen Library + Intel MKL + Visual Studio 2022 not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen, intel-mkl, eigenvector

I am trying to enable Intel MKL (2023.0.0) on Eigen C++ (3.4.0) library using Visual Studio++, so far I am able to run Eigen library in Visual Studio 2022 with no issues.

But as stated on this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408312/using-eigen-c-library-with-intel-mkl) and official [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html), when I try to enable Intel MKL by adding

```
#define EIGEN_USE_BLAS
#include <Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h>
```

I manage to compile and execute, but throws this error

> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to SGEMV .
>
> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 2 was incorrect on entry to SGEMV .

To enable Intel MKL on my Visual Studio project I added the include directories and library directories as stated here and the [Intel MKL linker advisor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html#gs.pwryhi), the libraries that the linker advisor recommends are

> mkl_intel_ilp64.lib mkl_sequential.lib mkl_core.lib

For those who are curious, the line of code that throws this error is

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> es(eig_cov);
```

I am basically trying to compute the eigen vectors for a matrix of 8192x8192 (the matrix is symmetric and has been validated with other libraries like OpenCV and Armadillo, they just take so long, I have another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75424748/eigen-methods-in-c-library-opencv-eigen-armadillo-considerably-slower-than) about this in case you are curious)

Since my program is able to compile and execute and fail at the line above, I would say I have my dev environment setup but I am not really sure why Intel MKL is not liking Eigen, any pointers will be appreciated

PD: I tried to use EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL instead of EIGEN_USE_BLAS, but I open a can of worms, looks more scary to solve that way.

Comment: Your issue is essentially the same as in the question you link to. You must not include headers from the `Eigen/src/...` subdirectories, but only `Eigen/Core` or `Eigen/Dense` etc.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the complete sample reproducer code and steps to reproduce (if any) as it helps reproduce/triage the issue at our end?